# recursive directory loop for symlinks in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/index.htm), but it is leaving many things unanswered for me. I have a folder on a mapped network drive that, for now, I just want to loop through the directory and for each file echo it (eventually I want to examine them and make symlinks...) here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
for /f %%f in ('dir /b "X:\path\to\stuff"') echo %%f
```

when I run this I am getting :echo was unexpected at this time. From what I can tell, this is a syntax error, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b "X:\path\to\stuff"') do echo %%f
```

you need **do**  ...

though if you have white spaces in file names it will be better to use:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%f in ('dir /b "X:\path\to\stuff"') do echo %%f
```

Comment: Thanks! writing batch files is a new endeavor for me, I haven't had much occasion for them.